# Dealing with Delays and Resource Provisioning Issues in Job Execution for Azure DevOps pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-agent

When any job runs in azure pipeline after 7 PM Pakistan Standard Time, I encounter an error that causes significant delays in job execution, approximately 20 to 25 minutes, or even leads to pipeline cancellations. Even I am using 2 Microsoft hosted agents for parallel jobs but they do not receive jobs

The error message is as follows:

> ##[warning]The remote provider has asked us to wait until 10/20/2023 2:38:07 PM before attempting to provision a resource. This will cause
> delays in the running of this request.

I have been experiencing a problem for the past 3 to 4 days, and it usually starts after 6-7 PM Pakistan Standard Time.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the following pages to check whether there is "[**Business Hours**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass#business-hours)" check set. Try to update the **`Start Time`** and **`End Time`** on the check, or delete the check:

- **Project Settings** > **Repositories** > select the repository which the pipeline runs for > **Approvals and checks**.
  [image]
- **Pipelines** > **Environments** > select the environment which is used by the pipeline > **Approvals and checks**.
  [image]

---

**EDIT:**

Also go to **Project Settings** > **Agent pools** > select the pool which the pipeline jobs run on > **Approvals and checks**.
[image]

Comment: there is no Approvals and checks added for Repository

Comment: @TahamiRizwan, how about Environments?

Comment: same . we haven't set any environment

Comment: @TahamiRizwan, I updated my above answer with more information.

Comment: I am using Microsoft hosted agent and same no Approvals and checks are added for them

Comment: @TahamiRizwan, Do the pipelines in your other Azure DevOps organizations within the same region have the issue occurs?

Comment: Yes my organization is in Australia East region

Comment: @TahamiRizwan, I mean whether the same issue occurs in your other organizations which are in the same region.

Comment: not all the organizations in same regions are effected

Comment: @TahamiRizwan, Did you try creating a new pipeline with the same definition as the effected pipeline, or creating the new pipeline with the same definition in the organization which is not effected?

Comment: haven't tried this yet

Comment: @TahamiRizwan, you can try it and provide the result.

Comment: have try this but for this  it is working

Comment: @TahamiRizwan, So, the issue does not affect the newly created pipelines, even if using the same definitions of the affected pipelines? If so, maybe, you can try to re-create all the affected pipelines.

Comment: I have 50+ build and release pipelines ....

Comment: @TahamiRizwan, For YAML pipelines, just need to set up the pipelines using the existing same YAML files. For classic pipelines, you can export and import the JSON type definition files to re-create the new pipelines.